# What is wrong with this 2-D associative array?

Tags: php, javascript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm trying to create a 2-D associative array in Javascript (first index numeric, second index associative). The page that I am designing will have multiple fields, and a drop-down menu that allows the user to select a different "date of update", and these fields will be repopulated with the values for that update. I am generating the javascript code using php:

Here is what the php code looks like (I formatted it to make it easier to read):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$i = 0;
echo "var updates = new Array();";
foreach ($risk_data['updates'] as $update) {
    echo "updates[" . $i . "] = new Array();";
    foreach ($update as $key => $value) {
        echo "updates[" . $i . "]['" . $key . "'] = '" . $value . "';";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>

function update_fields() {

    var update_index = document.getElementById('select_update').selectedIndex;
    alert(update_index);
    document.getElementById('impact').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact'];
    document.getElementById('probability').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['probability'] + '%';
    document.getElementById('impact_effect').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact_effect'];
    document.getElementById('cost_impact').innerHTML = '$' + updates[update_index]['cost_impact'];
    document.getElementById('overall_impact').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['overall_impact'];
    document.getElementById('expected_cost').innerHTML = '$' + updates[update_index]['expected_cost'];
    document.getElementById('impact_discussion').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact_discussion'];
    document.getElementById('priority_effect').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['priority_effect'];
    document.getElementById('priority_monetary').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['priority_monetary'];
}
</script>
```

And for your reference, here is what it looks like when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updates = new Array();
updates[0] = new Array();
updates[0]['date_of_update'] = '2013-08-26';
updates[0]['impact'] = 'delay in schedule';
updates[0]['probability'] = '18';
updates[0]['impact_effect'] = '79';
updates[0]['cost_impact'] = '21000.00';
updates[0]['overall_impact'] = '14';
updates[0]['expected_cost'] = '3780.00';
updates[0]['impact_discussion'] = 'Critical path items past schedule, invoke contract penalties. You can change a very limited number of settings related to formatting. open up netbeans IDE Go to tools->options click on Editor button on top left of the options dialog box click on lot';
updates[0]['priority_effect'] = '1';
updates[0]['priority_monetary'] = '1';

function update_fields() {

var update_index = document.getElementById('select_update').selectedIndex;
alert(update_index);
document.getElementById('impact').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact'];
document.getElementById('probability').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['probability'] + '%';
document.getElementById('impact_effect').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact_effect'];
document.getElementById('cost_impact').innerHTML = '$' + updates[update_index]['cost_impact'];
document.getElementById('overall_impact').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['overall_impact'];
document.getElementById('expected_cost').innerHTML = '$' + updates[update_index]['expected_cost'];
document.getElementById('impact_discussion').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['impact_discussion'];
document.getElementById('priority_effect').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['priority_effect'];
document.getElementById('priority_monetary').innerHTML = updates[update_index]['priority_monetary'];
document.getElementById('risk_statement').innerHTML = "If " + <?php
echo $risk_data['event'] . " by " .
 $risk_data['date_of_concern'];
?> + " then "  updates[update_index]['impact'] + ".";
}
</script>
```

But for some reason the script does not run at all. It is supposed to be called by the  element's "onchange" event, but nothing happens. I am not sure if the error may be in how I declared the array. If anyone has any tips, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode). It shall solve this problem quickly.

Comment: Yes, Never build javascript data/code directly if you can avoid it. Build a 2D PHP array, and json_encode() will spit out the JS equivalent for you automatically.  Your version is vulnerable to the JS equivalent of SQL injection attacks. Consider what happens if one of those values you're outputting contains  a JS meta-char?

Comment: [JavaScript has no associative arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Arrays `[]` are not associative, and are not at all like PHP arrays...

In PHP, you can do:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo"
);
```

and:

```
$array2 = array(
    "foo",
    "bar"
);
```

Being either associative or non-associative.

In JavaScript, what one would call an associative array is an Object-Literal (Arrays are also Objects, but don't let that confuse you at this point).

To mimic the same behavior as above, you would do:

```
var myArray = {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo",
};
```

and:

```
var myArray2 = [
    "foo",
    "bar"
];
```

With a JS object literal (myArray), you can use dot-notation to define properties: `myArray.foo = "bar";`, as well as `myArray["foo"] = "bar";`.

But for Arrays, you will need to use the `.push()` method: `myArray.push("bar");`

---

Though I do not recommend using PHP to create JavaScript Objects, you will need to change your function to use an object literal instead of an Array.

Some good reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects